# erreur:Pip could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, libfreenect2

Pip could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
find solution for this problem:
need help
pip install freenect

Causing these errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement freenect (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for freenect
```

Comment: There's no project named `freenect` on the PyPI.

Comment: You probably want `pip install freenect2`. Google is your friend.

Comment: What command did you run? What is your python version? Include your complete error message